# Minting token in cardano mainnet --tx-out error

Tags: linux, cardano

I am trying to mint a token in cardano mainnet. I have built a block and staking pool. I am working to mint a token and i am running into an error "unexpected '2', expecting space, "+" or end of input.

Here is the linux code I'm running:

```
cardano-cli transaction build-raw  --shelley-era  --fee $fee  --tx-in $txhash#$txix  --tx-out $address+$output+"$tokenamount $policyid.$tokenname1"  --mint="$tokenamount $policyid.$tokenname1"  --minting-script-file policy/policy.script --out-file matx.raw
```

Here is the error:

option --tx-out:
unexpected '2'
expecting space, "+" or end of input

Inputs:
I have tried different outputs of 10000000, 5000000, and 0.

```
$tokenamount="10000000"

$address=$(cat payment.addr)

$tokenname1="CpoolTest"
```

https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/minting/

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I guess i found the error.

Check `$policyid` whats inside. It should contain only 1x adress.

Try `echo $policyid`. It should only display 1 address

If its not the case, yo can try:

to delete your policyID:

```
rm -rf policy/policyID
```

After deleting create a brand new one:

```
cardano-cli transaction policyid --scriptfile ./policy/policy.script >> policy/policyID
```

Now set the variable:

```
policyid=$(cat policy/policyID)
```

Echo it

```
echo $policyid
```

There should be exactly 1 address displayed. Your code should work now